# Force iPhone Orientation

Tags: ipad, orientation, setorientation

I'm making an iPad app and I need to force the orientation to portrait to several parts of the app. I used the undocumented "setOrientation" API and the app was rejected. Is there a documented way to do this?

Comment: Why not override `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and only return YES in portrait orientation?

Comment: I've done that, but the problem is that when the user is in lanscape mode and taps the button, the view does not rotate. I really wish Apple would open up setOrientation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Apple only accepting iPad apps that work in any orientation.  I've heard they are quite strict about it and are really pushing the whole "there is no right way to hold it" idea. So unless you have a very good reason (such as for some games) you will probably have to find a way to make your UI work in landscape too.